# Clear cache in Rails 4.2 using cache_digests gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, russian-doll-caching

How can I clear cache in rails 4.2. My html.erb contain

```
<% @datas.each_with_index do |data, i| %>
    <% cache data do %>
        <tr class="">
            <td><%= i + 1 %></td>
            <td><%= data.value %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now the problem is that on adding new data my

```
<td><%= i + 1 %></td>
```

count does not increase that is before adding data count shows `1,2,3,4` and after adding data count shows `1,1,2,3,4`. Now the second problem is my `/tmp/cache` files are increasing regularly. Now How can I expire unused cache on adding and updating data.

Comment: define `@datas.each_with_index do |data, i = 1|` or what output you want?

Comment: Still does not work for me. I have added a new data and then redirected to back but still showing `1,1,2,3,4`

Comment: If you are using rails 4 then just use the default rails caching I suggest. Why are you using a unsupported gem. Here is the link which will help you for rails cache if you want to use that: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Ok Fine but what about `<td><%= i + 1 %></td>` how do i resolve this. And how to expire cache in sweeper after update in rails4.2 as it is not expiring cache in my case

Comment: cache sweeper is also deprecated. Instead you can manually expire the cache using the key on the particular action like `create/new`

Comment: No you can still use cache sweeper in rails4 and I think that is better way to keep code clean but other then  what about `<td><%= i + 1 %></td>` it is still caching old value